# Execute in bash command

Tags: linux, bash

When i execute this this command on the cmd line it executes fine. However when i execute by placing it in a bash file and then run the bash script it doesn't work. I am guessing this is because Iam not escaping the special characters properly ?

```
ps -ef | grep node | awk '/'launchPackager.command'/{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: You'll need to show exactly how you "run the bash script", and show the exact output/error.

Comment: Try running the script using bash -x <your-script-name> that should give you further clue on what might be going wrong. Post the output of the script to get further insight into what might be going wrong.

Comment: Do you know the `-f` option of the **[pkill command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)**?

Answer (score 0):

Just go sure that you make the file executable:

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

Just for debug purposes:

```
chmod 777 <filename>
```

You can also debug this with:

```
bash -x <filename>
```

Hope this helps you.

Have a nice day.